# I'm trying to find a short thriller film about a light bulb and kids in a room

Tags: story-identification, movie, short-film

I'm trying to find a short film I remember seeing about some kids that are fooling around in a warehouse and find a room with a light bulb inside. They go in and close the door thinking it would be cool to play with the light in the dark. They start playing with the light. Then the light starts playing back with them and each time the light turns itself off a kid disappears. The film ends with no more kids in the room.

Comment: Is the light green?

Comment: @Cassfrank No it's just a light bulb hanging from the ceiling with a little string that you pull to turn the light on or off.

Answer (score 5):

It was a short movie called *Click* from 2010. "Alter" was also in the title: